# What is the cordova version used in Mobilefirst 6.3?

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to use password field in the phonegap notification prompt. I could easily do it in ios as the Cordova code is available. But for android we just have the Cordova jar file added.So I want to create my own Cordova jar file using the Cordova source code. So which version of Cordova is used in MobileFirst 6.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3 uses Cordova v3.6.3.

Note though that IBM does not support swapping the provided Cordova version with your own, and in fact it will be overwritten on every build made in Studio.

For Android you may need to create your own UI instead of h[acking the notification.alert code](http://The%20command%20will%20ask%20which%20MobileFirst%20Server%20to%20deploy%20the%20artifacts%20to,%20and%20update%20the%20%3Ccode%3Ewlclient.properties%3C/code%3E%20file%20accordingly%20with%20the%20server%20address.) provided by Android.

Comment: Thanks alot Idan. I know its not supported but its a very small change and doesnt interrupt the workflow of MobileFirst.